# Debug laravel on production for admin

Tags: laravel

I can't find any proper way to turn on debug mode in `Laravel 5.4` on production only for admin.

I have an app, which I'm debugging on production all day, so I need debug mode which will be seen only for me.

Is it posible to set `APP_DEBUG=true`, instead of `APP_DEBUG=false`, which is in `.env` - on the fly in production? Or any other ways?

Comment: How are you splitting your admin and other areas?

Comment: This app doesn't require to login, so there is no Auth logic yet. So any way would be good, which can identify me as an admin - session, cookie, get params, ip address...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Technically its not possible **Authentication** comes way after **laravel** itself (especially **app.php**) defined so you cant write something like

`if (isAdmin)  {
   debug = true'
   }`

But what you can do is in `config/app.php` you can define debug like this and put your ip (be sure you are not using it in staging/local because you debug would return false in those cases too)

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your.ip.address' ? true : false)
```

Remove `APP_DEBUG` line from production `.env` file. When there will be no value, it will be taken from this condition. Leave it on `local` to set it as you wish.

So if it is your ip debug will be true otherwise false.

But I would say most secure and elegant way would be

1) Store logs in an authenticated route. Each error you get will be shown under a specific route as in log file aswell. 
but still it wont be instant. You can actually use package like this one 
https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer

2) Using a service as sentry and email each error yourself or use their own panel

Comment: you are genius! It is the first method which really worked in my case. To make it work perfectly, maybe it is possible to check or environment is local, then set true, if production, then check for ip to be true, else is false?

Comment: yup you can do  that

Comment: oh, I just realised I don't need that, because I can remove `APP_DEBUG` value on production .env, so it will be taken only from `config/app.php` condition. Thanks!

Comment: yes but in local if developers ip is different it will still get debug false you need to put a condition there about it

Comment: on development I set `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file, so firstly it takes value from it, only when it is empty - takes from `app.php` config

Comment: just change this : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '' === 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] doesn't exist in CLI (undefined error)